# Cassandra copy keyspace in a multi-node setup spanning multiple datacenters

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have a keyspace sample that I would like to make a copy of, on the same cluster.

I have a 6 node setup spanning two datacenters, 3 nodes in each dc, with a replication factor of 3 in each dc.

I am using version 3.0.17

I saw a similar question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49798459/cassandra-copy-keyspace-how-to) that mentioned the following steps.

1. Create SNAPSHOT of the keyspace
2. Create new KeySpace (${NEW_KEYSPACE}) and the tables
3. Copy the SNAPSHOT/*.db files to corresponding tables folder in $CASSANDRA_HOME/data/data/${NEW_KEYSPACE}
4. Refresh the KeySpace and the tables
5. Repair the KeySpace

I wanted to know if the copy of the snapshot files need to happen on just one node or all the nodes?

Also, would it change in case of a setup with more nodes than the replication factor, such that some of the nodes do not have 100% of the data?

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted to know if the copy of the snapshot files need to happen on just one node or all the nodes?
>
> Also, would it change in case of a setup with more nodes than the replication factor, such that some of the nodes do not have 100% of the data?

A snapshot only contains data for the node that it is taken on.  The issue where the number of nodes exceeds the defined RF, is exactly the one where you would need to take a snapshot on each node to ensure that you're getting all of the data.

However in your case, as all nodes are responsible for 100% of the data, you should need to take a snapshot on only one node.

**EDIT**

> What I also wanted to know was that as part of creating the new keyspace, do I need to copy the snapshot files on all the nodes, or can I just copy them on one of the nodes and then the repair process would move it to the other nodes?

As your RF == number of nodes per DC, you should only need to copy the files to one node, load them, and repair should take care of the rest.

Comment: Thanks for that information. 

What I also wanted to know was that as part of creating the new keyspace, do I need to copy the snapshot files on all the nodes, or can I just copy them on one of the nodes and then the repair process would move it to the other nodes?

Comment: @mayoite edit made.